# Geocoding addreses using PostGIS?

Tags: geocoding, postgis-2.4

I have a requirement where I am supposed to be able to take a reference address and provide the 3 closet addresses to the reference address from a list of addressses.

So far I have

1. Installed PostgreSQL
2. Installed PostGIS

From my reading online I believe I need to take an address and convert run it through a PostGIS function to get the latitude and longitude.

Since I have a list of addresses my thought is that I need to geocode the addresses first using the geocode function, then ST_MakePoint.

How do I get the geocode function to provide a latitude/longitude point?

Comment: if you need to geocode elsewhere than in US, I could not find instructions how to setup them easily. If you just need to geocode addresses in US then there are instructions, for example:  https://experimentalcraft.wordpress.com/2017/11/01/how-to-make-a-postgis-tiger-geocoder-in-less-than-5-days/, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MOIrEOFrkWc and even a docker container: https://hub.docker.com/r/moofish32/postgis-geocoder/. [PostGIS extras documentation](https://postgis.net/docs/Extras.html) mentions possibility to use Nominatim or GIS Graphy.

Comment: Geocoding 'with' PostGIS involves using the TIGER geocoder. However, using python / web services in conjunction with Psycopg2 you can read data from PostGIS, send it to a geocoding service, then dump the lat/lon results back into PostGIS... we've been using this method for a few years with much success.